# Cypher: Getting n neighboring Nodes for each Node of certain type

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j Sever 4.2.5.

The Pattern on which I want to run my query looks as follows:

`(Artist)-[similar_to {score: <float>}]->(Artist)`

Now what I want to do is get the 5 `[similar_to]` relations with the highest scores for each artist.

I've tried using Neo4j's `collect()` function to collect all the artists into a list and then using `UNWIND` to iterate over that. Sadly the `LIMIT` clause seems to limit the total number of returned records and not the returned records per iteration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 5 rels with the highest scores, this should do it.

```
MATCH (n:Artist)-[r:similar_to]->(:Artist)
WITH n,r 
ORDER BY r.score DESC
RETURN n, COLLECT(r)[..5] AS relsWithHighestScores
```